# Hilbert Sobolev Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I need a reference that helps me in working with Hilbert Sobolev Spaces. Is there any reference about "only" the Hilbert Sobolev Spaces? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look in Ralph Showalter's book 
http://fa.its.tudelft.nl/~sweers/papers/Showalter.pdf
It focuses on hilbert space methods specifically.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the area of evolution equations, I would recommend the book:

**Pascal Cherrier, Albert Milani - Linear and Quasi Linear Evolution Equations in Hilbert Spaces, 2010**

As it's name says it deals with the spaces $H^m$.

Hope this helps.